# How to display current value of a specific variable which is located in particular _KTHREAD object?

Tags: c, windows, struct, x86-64, windbg

OK so the following command (see below) displays all variable names and their type information of the structure _KTHREAD in **Windbg**. But if I have the address of a specific _KTHREAD object how can I display the **value** of a particular variable located in this struct ?

```
lkd> dt _KTHREAD
```

I then tried the following command in Windbg with a known address of a_KTHREAD object. Is this command correct ?

```
lkd> dt _KTHREAD FFFFA80000050000 WaitPrcb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the address

> dt _KTHREAD 0x12345

or if the address is in a register

> dt _KTHREAD @eax

Comment: @ Anders thank you for the answer. I will accept it. Can you tell me if I try the following command (lkd>dt _KTHREAD FFFFA80000050000 WaitPrcb) at the Windbg command line the value for WaitPrcb generated by Windbg is (null). Why ?

Comment: `dt name field address`